# what is the difference between UDID & advertising identifier?

Tags: ios

When advertising identifier is used does the App functionality will change? Will the App functions properly when the iPad/iPhone is resetted.

Answer (score 1):

**UDID**, which stands for *Unique Device Identifier*, is an alphanumeric string associated to Apple's iOS running Devices. Due to it's potential for abuse and privacy issues, Apple replaced it with the **Advertising Identifier** which is a:

> non-permanent, non-personal, device identifier, that advertising networks will use to give you more control over advertisers’ ability to use tracking methods. If you choose to limit ad tracking, advertising networks using the *Advertising Identifier* may no longer gather information to serve you targeted ads.

This **AdID** is used for advertising purposes and **does not changes** the functionality of the App in any way. It can even be disabled. Reseting it, though, may mean that you'll be receiving less accurate ads.

With **iOS 6.1** a button was added to **reset** the Advertising Identifier, so that future requests will return a different value.